# C# File.copy and Directory.CreateDirectory working on Win10 but in Win7 it appends folder to parent folder

Tags: c#, file-management, network-drive

The same code, one on windows 10, the other on windows 7.
The idea is to have a directory from a network drive replicate over to a local drive.
On windows 10, the machine I am writing it on, it works perfectly fine as intended.
On windows 7, the target machine, it 'works' but the sub folder structure is messed up.

Example,

C:\target               -> the target location

C:\targetNewFolderName1 -> What its being copied to

C:\targetNewFolderName2

C:\targetNewFolderNameN

When it should be doing this below,(which it is, on windows 10, not on windows 7)

C:\target                -> the target location

C:\target\NewFolderName1 -> What its being copied to

C:\target\NewFolderName2

C:\target\NewFolderNameN

Master is a network directory, @"\\server\fu\bar\target"

Slave is a local directory,     @"C:\target"

These are passed to the function.

Function header, private void CheckMasterToSlave(string MasterPath, string SlavePath, string BackupPath, string[] MasterFilesList, string[] SlaveFilesList)

The below code snipit is within a foreach; foreach (string master in MasterFilesList).

```
    log.Info(master + " doesnt exist, copying");
    string directoryCheck = (SlavePath + master.Substring(MasterPath.Length)).Substring(0, 
                            (SlavePath + master.Substring(MasterPath.Length)).LastIndexOf("\\"));
    if (!Directory.Exists(directoryCheck))
    {
       log.Debug(directoryCheck + " Directory not present, touching.");
       try
       {
           Directory.CreateDirectory((SlavePath + 
                                    master.Substring(MasterPath.Length)).Substring(0, (SlavePath + 
                                    master.Substring(MasterPath.Length)).LastIndexOf("\\")));
       }
       catch
       {
           log.Error(master + " directory failed to be created in slave environment.");
       }
   }
   try
   {
       File.Copy(master, SlavePath + master.Substring(MasterPath.Length));
       log.Info(SlavePath + master.Substring(MasterPath.Length) + " Successfully created.");
       BackupFile(master.Replace(MasterPath, SlavePath), BackupPath, SlavePath);
   }
   catch
   {
       log.Error(master + " failed to copy, backup has been halted for this file.");
   }
```

I do not understand why this works as intended on windows 10 but moving it to windows 7 causes this issue.
What would be causing this and how can I stop the new folder from appending to the parent folder in windows 7?

Comment: Learn to use all the tools available in `System.IO.Path` to manipulate paths. When you use `"\\"` and `+` and `Substring` and `LastIndexOf` and other general string utilities, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) to build a path name from different path components instead of just using string concatenation.

Comment: Hello, this makes readability better, I did not know of this thank you. I will be using the path.combine, but it does not solve the problem

Comment: Christ I am stupid, when testing, I have to build and install onto end machine.
So I made some changes which I will post in a moment. But I did not change to release. So I copied over the incorrect version without the changes. Of course that diddnt work.

But using Path.combine and some other weird things to account for sub folders. It did work.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I am stupid and forgot to change to release. When changes that NineBerry mentioned were made. It did work.
I still do not understand why the original did work on windows 10 but not on windows 7. Especially since the BackupFile portion does the same thing as the old 'wrong' way. But both work now.
Regardless, here is the updated bit.

```
log.Info(master + " doesnt exist, copying");

string[] EndDirectoryFile = master.Substring(MasterPath.Length).Split('\\');

string[] EndDirectory = new string[EndDirectoryFile.Length-1];
for (int i = 0; i < EndDirectoryFile.Length - 1; i++)
{
    EndDirectory[i] = EndDirectoryFile[i];
}

string directoryCheck = Path.Combine(SlavePath, Path.Combine(EndDirectory));

if (!Directory.Exists(directoryCheck))
{
    log.Debug(directoryCheck + " Directory not present, touching.");
    try
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryCheck);
    }
    catch
    {
        log.Error(master + " directory failed to be created in slave environment.");
    }
}
try
{
    File.Copy(master, SlavePath + master.Substring(MasterPath.Length));
    log.Info(SlavePath + master.Substring(MasterPath.Length) + " Successfully created.");
    BackupFile(master.Replace(MasterPath, SlavePath), BackupPath, SlavePath);
}
catch
{
    log.Error(master + " failed to copy, backup has been halted for this file.");
}
```